# Migrate .net solution from sqlite to microsoft sql ce

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, migration, sql-server-ce

I got a .net (wpf) solution using sqlite with the entity framework and I want to exchange the sqlite database to Microsoft Sql CE.

My questions are:
- what's the best way to migrate the database schema and data ?
- can i reuse all entity related code and just change the connection string ?
- are there anything I should be aware of ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the motivation for the change? What is the size and relative complexity of the database and the model?

Comment: The database and model is pretty simple, the database contains like 10 tables.